# How to do xml-c14n2 canonicalization

Tags: c#, .net, xml

.Net handles xml-c14n1 canonicalization already, there is inbuilt class available - XmlDsigC14NTransform. However, I have do this for xml-c14n2 using c#, please help.

Comment: What do you mean by "xml 2.0"?

Comment: canonicalization  which is for xml 2.0

Comment: @WiktorZychla I suppose OP means this: https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n2/ (which is not for xml 2.0 by the way).

Comment: You can use the schema on webpage Evk provided to create classes.  There are tools on-line that will create c# classes from the schema.  Then you can use xml serialize/de-serialize methods to go from the classes to xml or from xml to classes.